# S3 bucket policy restricting to IP CIDR range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-policy

I'm attempting to restrict S3 bucket access to EC2 instances that are within a few different subnets:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test.bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test.bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "192.168.129.64/27",
                        "192.168.129.96/27",
                        "192.168.128.64/26"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test.bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test.bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "192.168.129.64/27",
                        "192.168.129.96/27",
                        "192.168.128.64/26"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I know that there are other problems regarding the specificity of this policy, but I've tried to make it as bare-bones as possible except for the conditions. Unfortunately, trying a simple `aws s3 ls s3://test.bucket` from an ec2 instance with the IP address of `192.168.129.100` fails with an access denied. This policy has effectively locked me out of the bucket.

I don't know what I'm missing. I've even tried prepending `ForAnyValue` and `ForAllValues` to the `IpAddress` and `NotIpAddress` conditions.

Answer (score 6):

The IP address specified in the S3 bucket policy refers to the IP address from which the S3 web endpoint receives the request. There are a few things that will affect this.

In your policy, you specified a `192.168.*.*` CIDR block, which would be an **internal** IP address.

1. If you are executing the `aws s3 ls` command from outside of the AWS network (for example, on your local computer), then AWS will not see your local `192.168.29.100` IP address. Instead, it will see your publicly facing IP address. Check tools such as [What Is My IP Address?](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) to see what yours is. I think AWS has a similar tool, but I cannot find it right now.

If this is the case, you'll need to update your policy with your publicly facing IP address instead of your private one.

2. If you are executing the `aws s3 ls` command from inside the AWS network (for example, on an EC2 instance), and your VPC does not have "S3 VPC Endpoints" enabled, then (again), the S3 web endpoint is seeing the public IP address, not your private one. The reason being that the S3 command is exiting your VPC, becoming a public connection, then reaching the S3 endpoint.

If this is the case, you have 2 possible resolutions:

Resolution 1:

Update your policy to include the public IP address instead of your private one. Most likely this will be the public IP address of your NAT if your EC2 instance is in a private subnet, or the public IP address of your EC2 instance if your instance is in a public subnet.

Resolution 2:

Enable "S3 VPC Endpoints" on your VPC. This will create a direct connection between your internal VPC and S3 endpoints, thus bypassing the public internet.

Comment: Also, I *believe* there is a way back into the bucket, via an exception to this policy that allows deleting the bucket policy with `aws s3api delete-bucket-policy <bucket-name>` as long as you are using the **root credentials** (access-key-id and secret) of the AWS account that owns the bucket.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with a VPC endpoint for s3 that's been associated with all subnets in the VPC, the policy fails when I attempt to even list the contents of the bucket

Comment: Try principal as just `*`.

Comment: @MattHouser according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#Principal_specifying those principals are equivalent.